# Mule Studio ESB Invalid content was found starting with element 'xa-transaction

Tags: mule, mule-studio

when I choose Transaction Type change from No Transaction to XA Transaction this error appear

how I can fix it?

this is my config below

```
<flow name="insert_flow" doc:name="insert_flow">
    <jdbc-ee:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" queryKey="INSERT_TOKEN" queryTimeout="-1" connector-ref="Database" doc:name="Insert to mysql">
        <jdbc-ee:query key="INSERT_TOKEN" value="insert into users(FirstName) values(#[FirstName]);"/>
        <xa-transaction action="ALWAYS_BEGIN" interactWithExternal="true"/>
    </jdbc-ee:outbound-endpoint>
    <scripting:component doc:name="pyhon return success result">
        <scripting:script engine="jython">
            <scripting:text><![CDATA[result = str('{\"status\":\"true\"}')]]></scripting:text>
        </scripting:script>
    </scripting:component>
    <rollback-exception-strategy doc:name="Rollback Exception Strategy"/>
</flow>
```

Thank for advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue of the studio validation affecting version 1.3.x (details [here](http://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/STUDIO-2592) )

This has been fixed on Studio 3.4 and you can find informations about the beta in this [blog post](http://java.dzone.com/articles/mule-esb-and-mule-studio-34)

Comment: Thank you for response
I'm use version 1.3.2
And Mule-Runtime Server 3.3.2 EE
It's not transactional element

I'm beginner :(

Comment: Okay,It's work in Mule ESB 3.4 beta only.
But I have question about Rollback Exception Strategy.
How to config properties [When:] for test?

Comment: @Panupong,although the UI is showing an error while using Studio 1.3.2 the application will run.